# Outgoing packets from linux: Packets seen in tcpdump but not on destination

Tags: linux, networking, udp

I observed that UDP packets are sent by using `tcpdump`; also, the sending process didn't cause any error when `sendto()` was called. However, on the destination host (which is within the same subnet) the UDP packets are not seen.

Is there a possibility that kernel drops the UDP packets? And what can cause packets being dropped by kernel? If packets are being dropped, will this be recorded in any system logs on the sending side?

Packets origination server : 10.142.164.80 source port 2123
"tcpdump -ni any port 2123 -w /tmp/gtp_origin.pcap" command captures on 10.142.164.80, 100 packets are captured in the file and the
Destination End point : 10.142.164.96 destination port 2123
"tcpdump -ni any port 2123 -w /tmp/gtp_destination.pcap" doesnot show single packet in captured file.

Comment: I suggest to [edit] your question and add more details. Show the source and destination addresses of the packets and the IP addresses of the systems. How are the systems connected? To the same switch/hub? Virtual network? How do you detect that the packets don't arrive? Maybe you should show the `tcpdump` commands you use on sender and destination. Do you have any filtering rules configured?

Comment: You should not use `-i any` when troubleshooting. If you need to check everything, run one tcpdump per interface. And with option `-e` to display ethernet layer (and btw, also capture ARP and ICMP just in case)